# Training on Regional Proposal Network only for object detection using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I like to train only `RPN network` from `faster rcnn` using `tensorflow`.
In caffe, I have done training only RPN.

In tensorflow, [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn) shows training a customized network. Then [the other tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) here discussed how to train using models from [modelzoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).

So for my case, to train only RPN part, which approach is appropriate for me?
Say If I follow the first approach defining CNN network, how can I load `pretrained model` for `transfer learning`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To train RPN network only using tensorflow object detection api, you just need to change the config files because the API supports RPN only option as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/8367cf6dabe11adf7628541706b660821f397dce/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py#L23). To get the RPN only model, just add an option '`number_of_stages : 1`' in the model config [area](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/8367cf6dabe11adf7628541706b660821f397dce/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config#L8) (similar to '`num_of_classes : 90`'). (You can also remove some second stage parameters from the config file since they are useless if the `number_of_stages` is set to 1).

As for the second question of transfer learning, it is the same as if training the `faster rcnn` network, just need to make sure `from_detection_checkpoint` is true and `finetune_checkpoint_path` is correct in the [config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/8367cf6dabe11adf7628541706b660821f397dce/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config#L106).

During training process you can use tensorboard to check the status, once evaluation is performed, you can see in 'images' tab that region proposals are visualized on the image and the labels are all 'object + confidence score'.